# Connecting to MongoDB from Maven exec fails but not from the jar

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, jar

The command below resolves all required dependencies to execute my program:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com.cnrg.cdproc.App'`

but I can't connect to MongoDB with it, when it's possible to execute the same code from the jar using this command: `java -jar target/cdproc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`.

Here's the error I'm getting starting the app via maven:

```
[Thread-1] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:9032], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
[cluster-ClusterId{value='5fc969c67d495439ce9a3796', description='null'}-localhost:9032] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:9032
com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool 
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.acquirePermit(ConcurrentPool.java:203)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.PowerOfTwoBufferPool.getByteBuffer(PowerOfTwoBufferPool.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.PowerOfTwoBufferPool.getBuffer(PowerOfTwoBufferPool.java:77)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.getBuffer(SocketStream.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.getBuffer(InternalStreamConnection.java:684)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ByteBufferBsonOutput.getByteBufferAtIndex(ByteBufferBsonOutput.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ByteBufferBsonOutput.getCurrentByteBuffer(ByteBufferBsonOutput.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ByteBufferBsonOutput.writeByte(ByteBufferBsonOutput.java:77)
    at org.bson.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:150)
    at org.bson.io.OutputBuffer.writeInt32(OutputBuffer.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.writeMessagePrologue(RequestMessage.java:158)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:137)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:318)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.acquirePermit(ConcurrentPool.java:199)
    ... 23 more
```

What's the difference between starting the program through the jar and starting the program through maven? How to troubleshoot that issue if possible and start the program from maven?